# Wpf change application variable

Tags: c#, wpf, global-variables

I want to declare some application level variables. These variables changes with values on different pages. I declare a variable like this

```
<sys:String x:key="Item1">Test</sys:String>
```

Now in my code I want to change it so the code should be

```
Application.Current.Properties["Item1"] = "This is a test";
String t = (string)this.TryFindResource("Item1");
MessegeBox.Show(t);
```

but this code is not changing the value and it always gives "Test" Any Idea how to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application properties are unrelated to XAML resources.  Do this:

```
    Resources["Item1"] = "This is a test";
    String t = (string)this.TryFindResource("Item1");
    MessageBox.Show(t);
```

But *really* what you should probably be doing instead here is the MVVM pattern (google it)